# What are those huge one-letter files in Windows folder?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, windirstat

I used [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to display my hd content to find what take so much space. I found that there are five files of 15.9 GB in C:\Windows folder.

[image]

Does someone know what are those files? Can I delete them?

Comment: They all have a `S` flag meaning they are system files. Mess with these at your own risk!

Comment: @Burgi I know what `S` stands for. `S`=System, `H`=Hidden and `A`=Archive. But this does not explain me what are those files that are using almost one third the size of the hd.

Comment: use TreeSizeFree (started as admin) instead, it is much better: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/?language=EN

Comment: `Windows 7` sometimes downloads files needed to upgrade to `Win10` without the users permission. Those files might be related to the upgrade.

Comment: @MadocComadrin So now I am stuck with 80 GB of useless files. Because I won't upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: If you have recent system image as backup you could try deleting them. If something bad happens just do system restore from the image.