# Hidden Files: Odd large system files taking up space on hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, virus, malware

[image: []

In the above image there are four large files with names composed of what appear to be random (non-Roman) Unicode characters. I have no idea where they came from. Is anyone familiar with these? Do I have a virus?

They have HSA (Hidden, System & Archive) attributes. I have been able to see all hidden files and I have been able to locate these files. Upon trying to delete I have run a cmd to take ownership and rebooted to Safe Mode. Tried deleting the four files and it says that the "files are in use by another program". Under processes and services I do not know what to stop to be able to delete these files? Can I delete these? If so, how?

Comment: Boot from a linux live cd-dvd-usb and delete them.

Comment: Related, but without an answer: http://superuser.com/questions/1011504/what-are-those-huge-one-letter-files-in-windows-folder

Comment: A hint about the version of windows you use would help. Also the details of the files (yes windirstat shows big files but its the 4 files you're asking about that matter not the other 99' of the screenshot.)

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this, one example is like @Moab told you.

**First atempt:** 
I should restart my computer in safe mode instead.
[How to restart Computer in safemode 3 quick ways](http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Windows-in-Safe-Mode)
then delete the files manually.

**Second atempt:**

Download a program called Unlocker
[Download Unlocker Here](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/)

I have very hard to believe not of these altenatives should work if not.

**Last atempt:**
Download a Linux-Ubuntu Live DVD.
[Download Ubuntu live DVD HERE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)
select boot live only(Without install)
then navigate in **Gnome/KDE** to the files and delete them.
 then reboot

Regards

Xsi

Comment: please expand steps about unlocker and booting into safe-mode. (you can quote your source and list necessary steps here)

Comment: Used unlocker for hears. It can't always force a lock to be released or deleted on next boot

Answer (score 0):

Even safe mode locks some files.
Modern Windows and windows install dvds have a recovery/repair/advanced mode which will always work as a last resort.

Shift f10 or menus get you into command mode which you can use to delete any file as its not running that install of windows or locking its files.

From some situations you can also type explorer.exe to run the usual windows explorer from these places.

Comment: the commands you refer to depends totally on what computer you have got @Stilez

Comment: Not for this question :) The screenshot shows enough of the system to know its a version of windows modern enough that it'll have some form of install media or recovery mode with the features described. I don't say which commands to use because those can be researched (they aren't as much the focus of the question and the user can ask that detail if needed)